# Xcode Watch Simulator with wallet

Tags: xcode, xcode8, watchkit, watchos-2

Trying to test my iphone app with the wallet. I'm using Xcode 8 with a sim for both the iphone and wallet.
I can add the pass to the wallet just fine on the phone sim, but when I go to the watch sim, there's no wallet app.

Do I have to install it from somewhere?

I know the two simulators are paired together, as I can change the watch face.

These are the only available apps on the watch sim.

[image: Apple watch simulator]